# How to modified the __str__ method in django admin to print in two lines

Tags: django, django-admin

**MODEL**

```
class Linea_Invest(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True, unique= True)
    carrera = models.ForeignKey(
        Carrera, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['nombre', 'carrera'], name='no repetir nombre carrera linea')
        ]
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Linea de investigación:{self.nombre}\nCarrera: {self.carrera}"
```

This works in console, but when displaying in my template and in the admin I get something like this:
[image]

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Línea de investigación: Ingeniería del Software
Carrera: Ingeniería en Informática

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`format_html(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) function

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class Linea_Invest(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        html_content = "First Line <br>" \
                       "Second Line <br>" \
                       "Third Line"
        return format_html(html_content)
```

Comment: Worked with this:
`def __str__(self):
        return format_html("<i style=""color:DarkMagenta;"">Carrera:</i> {}</br><br><i style=""color:DarkMagenta;"">Línea de investigación:</i> </br> {}",self.carrera,self.nombre)`